# TutorialsPoint - RESTful API Example not working - Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make this RESTful example work in my browser but it keeps showing as not available.

The server.js uses a call to store the host variable which is being logged as ::

```
 var host = server.address().address
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       console.log( data );
       res.end( data );
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

console.log(host);

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

user.json

```
{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

Please can someone help me fix this. The server address is showing as ::

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but your code says "users.json" but in your question you have it labeled as "user.json". I'm guessing this is a typo in your question

Comment: Go to http://localhost:8081/listUsers in your browser. It's listening. Can you let us know what TutorialsPoint says the console output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `express()` app uses the `http` module from Nodejs, this is where it inherits the functionality of the `app.listen()` function.

Here is the excerpt about `server.address()` and `server.listen()`:

> #### server.listen(port[, hostname][, backlog][, callback])
>
> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise. A port value of zero will assign a random port.

So pretty much if you want to have the server listen at a specific address you need to provide it to the `hostname` parameter of your `app.listen()` function as such:

`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, 'localhost');`

The above code will default to listen on 3000 and will assign `localhost(127.0.0.1)` as the hostname. When you do, `console.log(server.address());` you willl see the following output:

`{ address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }`

Here is the full [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) for `server.listen()` from nodejs.